# Select argument doesn't work on cca objects

Tags: r, vegan

I created an object of class cca in vegan and now I am trying to tidy up the triplot. However, I seemingly can't use the select argument to only show specified items.
My code looks like this:

```
data("varechem")
data("varespec")
ord <- cca(varespec ~ Al+S, varechem)
plot(ord, type = "n")
text(ord, display = "sites", select = c("18", "21"))
```

I want only the two specified sites (18 and 21) to appear in the plot, but when I run the code nothing happens. I do not even get an error meassage.

I'm really stuck, but I am fairly certain that this bit of code is correct. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't recall now, but I don't think the intention was to allow "names" to select which rows of the scores should be selected. The documentation speaks of `select` being a logical vector, or indices of the scores to be selected. By indices it was meant *numeric* indices, not rownames.

The example fails because `select` is also used to subset the `labels` character vector of values to be plotted in `text()`, and this `labels` character vector is not named. Using a character vector to subset another vector requires that the other vector be named.

Your example works if you do:

```r
data("varechem")
data("varespec")
ord <- cca(varespec ~ Al + S, varechem)
plot(ord, type = "n")

take <- which(rownames(varechem) %in% c("18", "21"))
# or
# take <- rownames(varechem) %in% c("18", "21")
text(ord, display = "sites", select = take)
```

I'll have a think about whether it will be simple to support the use case of your example.

Answer (score 0):

The following code probably gives the result you want to achieve:

First, create an object to store the blank CCA1-CCA2 plot

```
p1 = plot(ord, type = "n")
```

Find and then save the coordinates of the sites 18 and 21

```
p1$p1$sites[c("18", "21"),]
#         CCA1      CCA2
#18  0.3496725 -1.334061
#21 -0.8617759 -1.588855
site18 = p1$sites["18",]
site21 = p1$sites["21",]
```

Overlay the blank CCA1-CCA2 plot with the points of site 18 and 21. Setting different colors to different points might be a good idea.

```
points(p1$sites[c("18", "21"),], pch = 19, col = c("blue", "red"))
```

Showing labels might be informative.

```
text(x = site18[1], y = site18[2] + 0.3, labels = "site 18")
text(x = site21[1], y = site21[2] + 0.3, labels = "site 21")
```

Here is the resulted plot.
[image]

Comment: This was very helpful. So I actually can't use ```select``` argument on cca objects? I thought I encountered a bug, since it works fine dca objects.